# Where to add "insert" query in PHP

Tags: php

I Have login page that i would like to add log file to it, meaning when user logs in it inserts user details to the database.

the first code is my working page

the second code is the statement that I want to insert in my code, but anywhere i add that code my page stops working or no data is passed to database

I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

```
<?php //http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/56A0W - shource code for login page.
require("includes/config/config.php"); 
$submitted_username = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    $query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt, email FROM susers WHERE username = :username"; 
    $query_params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);         
    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $login_ok = false; 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        } 
        if($check_password === $row['password']){
            $login_ok = true;
        } 
    } 
    if($login_ok)
    { 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
        header ("Location: includes/Sales/".$_POST["username"]."/".$_POST["username"].".php");
        die("Redirecting to: sales.php");
    }
    else {$err[]='Wrong username and/or password!'; //1
            header("Location: sales.php");  //2
    } if($err)  //3
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err); // 1 and 2 and 3 http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/ - source code for Error message
exit;
} ?>
```

second code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO suserlog (username) VALUES ( :username)";
```

I believe the code should go somewhere in

```
if($login_ok)
```

Comment: _...I am trying to merge them in to one..._ What is the reason for that? If both scripts are working fine as they are

Comment: _“I am trying to merge them in to one, but failing to do so”_ - that’s something you can say to people, if you just want them to pity you. If you want our help in fixing the problem though, then _you_ need to give us a proper problem description to begin with. Show us what you tried, explain what results you got. [ask], [mre]

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?  For example, if by "merge" you mean that you interlaced the files line by line then, yes, that would fail for a variety of reasons.  Or if by "merge" you mean that you tried to put all of the lines of code side-by-side then that would fail as well.  Perhaps you tried something else?  Perhaps you could share information about the problem?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - have no idea what u saying

Comment: You have Plain Text Passwords in your Second Script! PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks but that another problem that i am not trying to solve now

Comment: Please don't post code chunks in comments. It's unreadable. It also doesn't help that you haven't told anyone what code it is.

Comment: You cannot merge these 2 scripts. They appear to handle the password in a completely different way

Comment: _"thanks but that another problem that i am not trying to solve now"_ - That's backwards. Implementing security best practices should be a top priority. Also, when you implement them, you would need to rewrite parts of your code, which makes it a waste of time to debug it before that's done. Who knows, when you implement prepared statements and proper password hashing, you might even solve your issue at the same time.

Comment: i dont whant to merge all the code, just the insert part, where its creating log entry in DB

Comment: You still have not shown us how exactly you actually tried to do that, and neither have you explained how it fails.

Comment: @04FS fails in that way, that i get nothing passed into DB. what i tried to do is; insert second code into the first code just after this line `$_SESSION['user'] = $row;`

Comment: @B001ᛦ what about now?

Comment: @RiggsFolly what about now?

Comment: @04FS what about now?

Comment: What about _What about now_ ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly changed the question narrowed down to smaller problem, can you help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, thanks

```
<?php 
require("includes/config/config.php"); 
$submitted_username = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    $query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt, email FROM susers WHERE username = :username;"; 
    $query .= "INSERT INTO suserlog (username) VALUES ( :username)";
```